# How can I move library files with macOS Catalina's new media apps (Music.app, TV.app)?

Tags: music.app, tv.app

Just as with iTunes before them, the new media apps allows us to create a new library, or select an existing library by holding <kbd>alt</kbd> and double-clicking the application's bundle in `~/Applications`.

But when I try to do this, I always get a dialog with this message:

> You cannot change the video library at this time because the current library is in use by a device. Sign in without connected devices to change your video library.

I 'ejected' my iPhone in Finder and it's not even on Wi-Fi as I try this. I have also signed out of my Apple ID in System Preferences.

I'd like to move the library files somewhere else, because I don't find the default locations agreeable. How can I do this?